# NHIbernate readonly property - fluent mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, readonly

I have the next entity:

```
public class Topic : EntityBase
{
    private readonly ICollection<Vote> _votes;

    public virtual string Title { get; protected set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Vote> Votes
    {
        get { return _votes; }
    }

    public virtual int VotedUpCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _votes.Count(v => v.VotedTo == VoteType.VoteUp);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to map my `VotedUpCount` (because I have an error from NH). **BUT** I don't need this property as column in my database.

I tried this one and got an error `Invalid column name 'VotedUpCount'.`

```
public class TopicMap : ClassMap<Topic>
{
    public TopicMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Title);
        Map(x => x.VotedUpCount).Access.ReadOnly();
        HasMany<Vote>(x => x.Votes)
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to map readonly properties using fluent interface to make this entity working?

Comment: You accepted an answer that shouldn't work for your situation *based on the wording of your question*. Please edit the question to match the answer or un-accept the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why do you want to map it? It's just a .NET property executing some code (that could also be a method) and has nothing to do with the database, just don't map it at all.

If you need a real DB property (where the value comes from a DB column) mapped as readonly:

```
Map(x => x.PropertyName).Column("ColumnName").ReadOnly();
// Alternative (does exactly the same, but is more like the NHibernate mapping:
Map(x => x.PropertyName).Column("ColumnName").Not.Insert().Not.Update();
```

Comment: For example, I have a predefined data, and I've loaded it into DB. I want to make data invariable, how can I do it ?

Comment: @Anton In your question you said that you don't have the property in the DB. Anyway, I've updated my answer to contain a readonly DB property mapping.

Comment: Testing the two versions: .ReadOnly(); and .Not.Insert().Not.Update();
 I determined that they are not "exactly the same" and they actually have different consequences (perhaps a bug in fluent). .Not.Insert().Not.Update();  cannot be used with a second field mapped to the same column, because on update it will list the column twice in the sql clause.